# Missing data for input "dense_input" You passed a dataset with ['img','img/filename','labels','labels_no_difficult_objects'] Expected:['dense_input']

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from numpy.core.memmap import ndarray
from tensorflow_datasets.object_detection.voc import Voc
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



voc = tfds.object_detection.voc
image_train , image_test = (tfds.load(name = 'voc', split = ['train','test'] ))

label_train , label_test = (tfds.load(name = 'voc', split = ['train','test']))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units =10 , input_shape=(0,0,3)),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1) , loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x=image_train, y=None,  epochs = 500)
```

output:

```
Missing data for input "dense_84_input". 
You passed a data dictionary with keys ['image', 'image/filename', 'labels', 'labels_no_difficult', 'objects']. 
Expected the following keys: ['dense_84_input']
```

What is the problem here. I also tried making the data into a numpy array and it didn't work either

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.